# How to select which files to commit in two different branches (subprojects)?

Tags: git

I have been working on a project which is composed of two different subprojects (A and B), each of which has its own branch.

```
/projectA
    /subprojectA
        fileA.py
    /subprojectB
        fileB.py
```

Let's say I have been working on `"subprojectA"` branch and modified files belonging to both `subprojectA` and `subprojectB` (`fileA.py` and `fileB.py` in this example).

So if I did `git status` when being on branch `subprojectA` (for example) I would see the following:

```
$ git status

# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   project/subprojectA/fileA.py
#   modified:   project/subprojectB/fileB.py
```

I need to commit only the files belonging to `subprojectA` when I am on `branch A`, and then change to `branch B` and commit only the files belongig to `subproject B`.

How could this be done? How could I say "from all the files that I have modified, include only these certain files in this commit in this branch" and "get other files, take them to another branch and commit them there"?

Comment: By the way, using separate repositories for different projects could be helpful

Comment: Additional to @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ comment, you could still have them as submodules in a parent repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're on the branch for one of the projects, let's say

```
git checkout proA/featureX
```

add the changes and commit them

```bsh
git add subprojectA  # assuming you're in the repo's top level folder
git commit -m "Glorious updates to A"
```

Change to the other branch, and do the same

```bsh
git checkout proB/fixing-Y
git add subprojectB
git commit -m "Fabulous bugfixes to B"
```